# Display a Modal on button click using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to display my Modal on button click. Below is my code.

```
<input type="button" id="button1" value="Button" onclick="myFunction()"/>
<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
    <div>
        <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
        <h2>
            Modal Box</h2>
        <p>
            Hello world</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my unfinished script.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () { 

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`show` openModal div on `button1` click.

```
$('#button1').on('click', function() {
    $('#openModal').show();
});
```

No need of `onclick="myFunction()"` on `button`

Comment: Hi Tushar, can you help me with a query - in the HTML page where shall i code the modal?? as i tried the above approac i can see the nodal div content on the load of the page.

Answer (score 3):

**Let's try...**

Simple popup model created by using jquery, HTML, and CSS.

```js
$(function() {
    // Open Popup
    $('[popup-open]').on('click', function() {
        var popup_name = $(this).attr('popup-open');
 $('[popup-name="' + popup_name + '"]').fadeIn(300);
    });
 
    // Close Popup
    $('[popup-close]').on('click', function() {
 var popup_name = $(this).attr('popup-close');
 $('[popup-name="' + popup_name + '"]').fadeOut(300);
    });
 
    // Close Popup When Click Outside
    $('.popup').on('click', function() {
 var popup_name = $(this).find('[popup-close]').attr('popup-close');
 $('[popup-name="' + popup_name + '"]').fadeOut(300);
    }).children().click(function() {
 return false;
    });
 
});
```

```css
body {
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
 
p {
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 26px;
    letter-spacing: 0.5px;
    color: #484848;
}
 
/* Popup Open button */ 
.open-button{
    color:#FFF;
    background:#0066CC;
    padding:10px;
    text-decoration:none;
    border:1px solid #0157ad;
    border-radius:3px;
}
 
.open-button:hover{
    background:#01478e;
}
 
.popup {
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    display:none;
}
 
/* Popup inner div */
.popup-content {
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 40px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,1);
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: #fff;
    position: relative;
}
 
/* Popup close button */
.close-button {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -10px;
    right: -10px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration:none;
}
 
.close-button:hover {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,1);
}
 
@media screen and (max-width: 720px) {
.popup-content {
    width:90%;
    } 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title> Popup </title>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head> 

<body>
    <a class="open-button" popup-open="popup-1" href="javascript:void(0)"> Popup 
        Preview</a>
         
        <div class="popup" popup-name="popup-1">
            <div class="popup-content">
            <h2>Model </h2>
        <p>Model content will be here. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
        consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam consequat diam ut tortor 
        dignissim, vel accumsan libero venenatis. Nunc pretium volutpat 
        convallis. Integer at metus eget neque hendrerit vestibulum. 
        Aenean vel mattis purus. Fusce condimentum auctor tellus eget 
        ullamcorper. Vestibulum sagittis pharetra tellus mollis vestibulum. 
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        <a class="close-button" popup-close="popup-1" href="javascript:void(0)">x</a>
            </div>
        </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this doesn't let the user to submit  the form

Answer (score 1):

Change `show()` to `modal.show()`;

```
$('#button1').on('click', function() {
    $('#openModal').modal('show');
});
```

Comment: `modal.show()`, or `modal('show');`, you use both?  Also, I think this is a Bootstrap solution?  But OP is not using Bootstrap.

Answer (score -1):

You probably have to set visibility:hidden; to the div, and set it to visible onclick